# Testing code using a watch service

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, integration-testing, watchservice

I'm trying to unit test a small piece of logic that is using WatchService (Java 7). Although, this is proving to be more difficult than anticipated because of the infinite loop:

```
watchService.take();
while (key!=null) {
        for (WatchEvent ev : key.pollEvents()) {
            //CODE I want to test
        }
      key.reset();
    }
}
```

Any ideas how I would go about doing this? Is it even possible to implement the same functionality without using an infinite loop? Also, I'm not sure I understand the difference between key.take() and key.pollEvents(). Do I need both?

Answer (score -1):

`take()` blocks until something happens. `pollEvents()` then gives you the specific event(s).